# Getting UK Student Visa in Time for Trip to France

Tags: visas, usa, uk, passports

I am a USA resident and citizen and I’ll be applying for a student Visa to study in the UK. However, I’m only able to apply for my Visa starting between August 19-26th depending on how fast my CAS is sent. I also have a flight to France scheduled on August 27th, where I intended to stay until beginning studies in the UK. Is there any was to make these two compatible, especially given that the UK Visa process takes your passport? My current ideas were buying Super Priority Service to get a decision within 24h, but do I still have to wait for my passport to be mailed? My second thought was to pay to keep my passport, then mail my passport from France upon a decision. Is this allowed?

Comment: I’m not sure from your question, but have you investigated applying from France?

Comment: @Traveller Tier 4 (student) requires the application be made in your country of legal residence